# Style nested list elements children, grandchildren and more

Tags: css, function, sass, nested

I need a loop for lists elements to style their bullets.
children - green
grandchildren - blue
grand grandchildren - gray
grand grand grandchildren - green
grand grand grand grandchildren - blue
grand grand grand grand grandchildren - gray

I created a CodePen to explain what I mean.
https://codepen.io/Pepe199111/pen/yLoddog

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqsbm.png)

At the moment I added CSS styles but it works only for the first 3 lines.

```
ul {
margin-bottom: 20px !important;
font-weight: 800;
list-style: none;

li::before {
  content: "\25CF ";
  color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: -1em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
}

ul {
  li::before {
    content: "\25CF ";
    color: blue;
  }
}

ul {
  ul {
    li::before {
      content: "\25CF ";
      color: gray;
    }
  }
}

ul {
  ul {
    ul {
      li::before {
        content: "\25CF ";
        color: green;
      }
    }
  }
}

ul {
  ul {
    ul {
      ul {
        li::before {
          content: "\25CF ";
          color: blue;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

ul {
  ul {
    ul {
      ul {
        ul {
          li::before {
            content: "\25CF ";
            color: gray;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

If there are more nested elements to make it work for them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list of colors and a list to keep track of nesting level

```
ul {
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
    font-weight: 800;
    list-style: none;

    li::before {
        content: "\25CF ";
        display: inline-block;
        width: 1em;
        margin-left: -1em;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    $bullet-colors: (red, orange, yellow, chartreuse, blue, purple);    
    
    // list to add one level of nesting per loop
    $parent-items: null;
    @each $color in $bullet-colors {
        #{$parent-items} li::before { color: $color; }
        $parent-items: append($parent-items, li);
    }
}
```

Loop Output

```
ul li::before { color: red; }
ul li li::before { color: orange; }
ul li li li::before { color: yellow; }
ul li li li li::before { color: chartreuse; }
ul li li li li li::before { color: blue; }
ul li li li li li li::before { color: purple; }
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that we are looping only the colours. So if I have 3 colours in $bullet-colors, the 4th, 5th, 6th ...  nested elements will have the same colour as the 3rd one.

Comment: The effect I need is here. https://codepen.io/Pepe199111/pen/yLoddog
The 1st,4th,7th,10th layer will have the same color - green.

Comment: At the moment there is no way of making style variations based on nesting level –why you would have to define classes for each li tag e.g. <li class="green">. The non class approach renders a finite number of nesting levels – in the example based on the $bullet-colors list. The colors can be repeated in the list as it is the length that determines the nesting level  - e.g $bullet-colors: (green, blue, gray, green, blue, gray, green, blue, gray, green, ....);

Comment: You're right, but I don't know how many nested levels will be there. I can simply expand variable $bullet-colors and add more colours there, but what if there will be 100 levels. How big $bullet-colors will be then.

Comment: If we are talking 100 nested levels i would use the class  <li class="green"> and define it in the HTML during render this way you only need 3 classes e.g.   .green::before { color: green; }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that we are looping only the colours. So if I have 3 colours in $bullet-colors, the 4th, 5th, 6th ... nested elements will have the same colour as the 3rd one.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6heFV.png)